# how to migrate to new TokenBasedRememberMeServices API

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

After switching to Spring 3.1 Eclipse started to complain about our current implementation of `TokenBasedRememberMeServices`. The class extending it has a parameterless constructor which has been deprecated. The [new constructor accepts two params](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.html#TokenBasedRememberMeServices%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService%29).

An extract from applicationContext-security.xml :

```
<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="MyRememberMeServices"
  p:key="${rememberMeServices.key}">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
</bean>
```

What's the easiest way of moving to the new API?

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor injection:

```
<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="MyRememberMeServices">
    <constructor-arg value="${rememberMeServices.key}" />
    <constructor-arg ref="userDetailsService" />
</bean>
```

Obviously you'd add a corresponding constructor in your `MyRememberMeServices` which calls the parent class.